# How to fix class imbalance in dialogue (text) time series data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm, class-imbalance

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df.head(5)


 data                                                     labels
0  [0.0009808844009380855, 0.0008974465127279559]             1
1  [0.0007158940267629654, 0.0008202958833774329]             3
2  [0.00040971929722210984, 0.000393972522972382]             3
3  [7.916243163372941e-05, 7.401835468434177e243]             3
4  [8.447556379936086e-05, 8.600626393842705e-05]             3
```

The 'data' column is my X and the labels is y. The df has 34890 rows. Each row contains 2 floats. The data represents a bunch of sequential text and each observation is a representation of a sentence. There are 5 classes.

I am training it on this LSTM code:

```
data = df.data.values
labels = pd.get_dummies(df['labels']).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 42)

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],1,X_train.shape[1])) # shape = (31401, 1, 5)
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1])) # shape = (3489, 1, 5)
### y_train shape =  (31401, 5)
### y_test shape =  (3489, 5)

### Bi_LSTM
Bi_LSTM = Sequential()
Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32)))
Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Dropout(.5))
# Bi_LSTM.add(layers.Flatten())
Bi_LSTM.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))

def compile_and_fit(history):

    history.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = history.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=30,
              batch_size=32,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    return history

LSTM_history = compile_and_fit(Bi_LSTM)
```

The model trains, but the val accuracy is fixed at 53% for every epoch. I am assuming this is because of my class imbalance problem (1 class takes up ~53% of the data, the other 4 are somewhat evenly distributed throughout the remaining 47%).

How do I balance my data? I am aware of typical over/under sampling techniques on non-time series data, but I can't over/under sample because that would  mess with the sequential time-series nature of the data. Any advice?

Comment: Does each row represent a training sample? If yes, your input only has 2 dimensions, which is quite small. This might be too little for your network to learn. Actually, with only 2 dimensions, you might be better off with more classical techniques (i.e. tree learning)

Comment: My input actually has 12 dimensions, I just reduced it for this example for easier reading. Yes, each row represents a training sample. Is this still too small? If so, why? The data performs well on classical techniques (SVM), but these don't take into account the sequential nature of the date, which is relevant, so I would assume the LSTM would perform better?

Comment: Can you elaborate on these 12 dimensions? It's not very clear for me? Are all 12 dimensions sequential?

Comment: Each row was originally text as part of a conversation. Each row is sequential in the sense that in a conversation, each utterance is dependent on the previous utterance, etc.  Each utterance is labeled 1 of 5 classes. The 12 dimensions are a vector representation of the sequences that I am experimenting with. Each text-based utterance was converted to a 12 dimensional vector. Does that make sense?